# Flash CS4 pass variable from javascript function to actionscript and back

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I want to pass the result of a js function into actionscript when the js function is called from actionscript. The js parses a url and returns the var in the url.
In actionscript the functions are declared:

```
function gup(name1:String) :void {
flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("gup", name1);

}

function printAlert(group2:String) :void {
flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("printAlert", group2);

}
```

then later in actions I call gup() which should return the var which I turn around and print as an alert to check what value is there.  "group" is the name of the var I want to get out of the url to use for branching in the swf. If I just define whichGroup the alert works fine. trying to get the return value of the js function the alert value is null

```
var whichGroup = gup("group");

printAlert(whichGroup);
```

Comment: Are `printAlert` and `gup` functions defined in the javascript? Your functions doesn't seem to handle the return value of js functions at all

Answer (score 1):

ActionScript

```
function printAlert(group2:String):void {
    var retValue:String = ExternalInterface.call("printAlert", group2);
    trace(retValue);
}
```

javascript:

```
function printAlert(grp) {
   return "Received group " + grp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with something very similar.  function printAlert(group:String) :void {
flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("printAlert", group);
    
}                                                            Using     var retData:String = ExternalInterface.call("gup","group");  in later frame javascriptfunction gup is a function that has a regular expression to get the vars out of a url                       printAlert(group){
alert("grouppa=" + group);
}